# Attempting to select node based on element value

Tags: xslt

I have a file that as shown below.
I need to process the file and copy the  nodes based on the element value  = CT.  I'm kind of lost on how or where to start.  Any help would be appreciated.

Stylesheet:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
    >
      <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

      <xsl:template match="/">
        <feed>
          <xsl:for-each select="web-export/run-date/pub-code/ad-type">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </feed>
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<web-export>
<run-date>02/01/2017
<pub-code>News
<ad-type>Legal Liner
<cat-code>Legals</cat-code>
<class-code>Legal</class-code>
<subclass-code>Briefings</subclass-code>
<placement-description></placement-description>
<position-description></position-description>
<subclass3-code></subclass3-code>
<subclass4-code></subclass4-code>
<order-number>0000023456</order-number>
<FieldedDataSet>
<State>CT</State>
</FieldedDataSet>
<ad-content><![CDATA[Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque est. ]]></ad-content>
</ad-type>
</pub-code>
<pub-code>News
<ad-type>Legal Liner
<cat-code>Legals</cat-code>
<class-code>Legal</class-code>
<subclass-code>Notices</subclass-code>
<ad-number>0000012345</ad-number>
<FieldedDataSet>
<State>RI</State>
</FieldedDataSet>
<ad-content><![CDATA[Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque est. ]]></ad-content>
</ad-type>
</pub-code>
</run-date>
</web-export>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

worked if any of child element has value ="CT"

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <feed>
        <xsl:for-each select="web-export/run-date/pub-code/ad-type[descendant::FieldedDataSet/State[. = 'CT']]">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </feed>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi Rupesh.  Thanks for the quick response.  This does work for me.  How would I target that specific element - <FieldedDataSet><State>?  There may be other elements that contain the string 'CT'.  I need to make sure only the entries for that element succeed.  Thanks.,

Comment: @geektampa i have edit the answer for you, now it will work only state matches.

Comment: Thank you.  works perfect.  That will come in handy.  Thanks for teaching me something new today.